# poetry install won't install the package

Tags: python, python-poetry, typer

I have this `.toml` file:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "ariel-tar-jfrog"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["ariel <ariel.tar99@gmail.com>"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
ariel-tar-jfrog = "ariel_tar_jfrog.main:app"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
typer = {extras = ["all"], version = "^0.4.0"}

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

I have this directory tree:

```
.
└── ariel-tar-jfrog
    ├── ariel_tar_jfrog
    │   ├── creds.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── main.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       └── creds.cpython-38.pyc
    ├── poetry.lock
    ├── pyproject.toml
    ├── README.md
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_ariel_tar_jfrog.py
```

Basically, this is a CLI application using 'typer'

I ran the command

```
poetry add typer[all]
```

edited the `.toml` file as you can see above.

The problem:
When I run `poetry install` it finished successfully, yet when I try to run `ariel-tar-jfrog` from the shell it returns `"command not found"`

I need to be able to install my project on a host machine. How does one do this in poetry?

I followed this tutorial: https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/package/

Comment: That may be stupid (and late) question but did you `poetry shell` after install and before running command?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I would try changing the name of the folder to match the name of the program. You have dashes on the parent dir and underscores on the py dir. I also struggled with this and got things to work once I aligned my naming.

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap your string with quotes:

```bash
poetry add "typer[all]"
```

In the shell, bare square brackets get expanded and are meant for conditional expressions. Wrapping them with double or single quotes means "literal square brackets" here, which is what you want.

Comment: Square brackets are used for character classes in wildcard expressions. Unquoted `typer[all]` will be expanded to `typera` and/or `typerl` if you have files with these names in the current directory (also depending on the shell's configuration; with `nullglob` it could also be expanded to nothing if you don't have matching files in the current directory).

Comment: This isn't the issue, because as you can see, the dependency did get added to the TOML file.